# How to use axiom of extensionality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, first-order-logic

Assume $x = y$ and we want to proof $\{x\} = \{y\}$. I read that this follows from the axiom of extensionality. The axiom states: $\forall x \forall y (\forall z( z \in x \iff z \in y) \implies x = y)$. Obviously $z \in \{x\} \iff z = x \iff z = y \iff z \in \{y\}$ so $\{x\} = \{y\}$. Am I doing this correctly or am I assuming things I can't directly assume? For example do I need to proof that $z = x \iff z = y$ with axioms or is this just a consequence of substitution.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it right.  I think somewhere you may have a definition of what $\{a,b\}$ means (I'd guess it'd have to be something like $\{a,b\} = \{x|x =a \text{ or }x=b\}$) and maybe you can use that. The gist is $\{x\}$ is the set that contains a single element $x$.  As $x$ is $y$ then $\{x\}$ is the set that contains a single element $y$.  So $\{x\}=\{y\}$.... but I'm not certain of what you basic definitions or axioms are.  But I certainly see nothing wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: So I believe in this example x and y are sets, the book writes the axioms in the language $\{ \in \}$ if that makes sense. So sets are defined by relations.

Comment: Doesn't matter what $x,y$ are.  They are elements of sets (whether or not they are sets themselves).  The axiom as you have written will apply as:  $\forall z(x\in \{x\} \iff z\in \{y\}) \implies \{x\} = \{y\}$.  It's pretty clear that, as you state $z \in \{x\} \iff z=x$ and As $x=y$,  $z=x \iff z=y$.  And $z \in \{y\}\iff z=y$ and thus we are done.

Comment: Extentionality is normally used indirectly. Use Extentionality to show that for any two sets A,B, (A $\subset$ B $\wedge$  B $\subset$ A ) $\iff$ A = B. Once you have that general result, you can show that {x} = {y} by establishing that they are subsets of each other. Extentionality is rarely used to directly show that two sets are equal. Saying that, what you wrote is perfectly correct. To answer your question, z = y $\iff$ z = x, if x = y and x = z, follows from one of the defined properties of =, that it satiafies a transitivity principle. There's nothing you need to prove, there.

Comment: Your particular question about $z = x \iff z = y$ follows immediately from $x = y$, and transitivity of equality. If equality is a primitive in the theory (in set-only theories, extensionality is often the definition of equality, rather than an axiom), then transitivity of equality is typically another axiom.